# Docker - Unable to find any JVMs - Error checking TLS connection

Tags: docker

I am just doing the [docker installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_one/). After the install I open "Docker Quickstart Terminal" (Step 3). I am getting this error:

```
bash --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8.60".
Error checking TLS connection: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :


                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

I checked my java version:

```
➜  ~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

I am using OSX 10.11.3 and iTerm with Zsh.

What's wrong?

---

EDIT:

This is the output of running `docker-machine ls`:

```
➜  ~ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running                 Unknown   Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

Comment: What do you get when you run docker-machine ls? It looks like you don't have the virtual machine running, or your configuration isn't setup correctly to connect to the correct Docker daemon.

Comment: Hi @KenCochrane. I added the output that I get from 'docker-machine ls'. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your virtualbox instance is running but isn't running correctly and it can't connect to docker. you have two options.

1. Remove the virtualbox instance and create a new one. (only delete if you are sure you don't need anything else)

`$ docker-machine rm default`

`$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

2. This is more work, but worth it if you need to save stuff on the VM. Try and find out what is wrong with the virtualbox instance and fix it.

Firs try restarting

`$ docker-machine restart default`

try sshing into the virtualbox

`$ docker-machine ssh default`

If you can get into the VM, then you can find out if docker is running and if not, try and get it running.

Comment: Since this is the first time I am using Docker, I haven't had anything to save on the vm. So I went with option 1. Which worked like a charme. Thank's a lot.